# SpriteKit Spritenode rotate 90 degrees

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift4

I'm trying to create a game in which the player rotates a spritenode to hit the right spritenode with the right color. I places a spritenode (node1) that is pinned to the main screen and jointFixed 4 spritenodes in each direction. (redPoint, bluePoint, greenPoint and brownPoint). When the player touches node1 sprite it should rotate 90 degrees. The color sprites should stay locked onto node1 and move in the right direction.

almost everything works as it should, the color sprites are fixed in the position on node1. However the whole group doesn't rotate 90 degrees as it should. It rotates but its not 90 degrees.

If I comment out everything except the node1 and test touching the sprite it indeed rotates 90 degrees.

**Does someone know what I can do to fix this?
Or am I doing something wrong or does someone have a different approach?**

I'm attaching the code I used:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {  

    var node1 = SKSpriteNode()
    var redPoint = SKSpriteNode()
    var bluePoint = SKSpriteNode()
    var greenPoint = SKSpriteNode()
    var brownPoint = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        playerTri()
    }

    func playerTri(){

        node1 = SKSpriteNode(color: .black, size: CGSize(width: self.size.width * 0.2, height: self.size.width * 0.2))

        redPoint = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: node1.size.width * 0.5, height: node.size.width * 0.5))
        bluePoint = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: node1.size.width * 0.5, height: node1.size.width * 0.5))
        greenPoint = SKSpriteNode(color: .green, size: CGSize(width: node1.size.width * 0.5, height: node1.size.width * 0.5))
        brownPoint = SKSpriteNode(color: .brown, size: CGSize(width: node1.size.width * 0.5, height: node1.size.width * 0.5))

        node1.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.minY + node1.size.height)
        node1.zPosition = 2
        node1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: node1.size)
        node1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        node1.physicsBody?.pinned = true
        node1.zRotation = 0.0

        redPoint.position = CGPoint(x: node1.frame.minX, y: node1.frame.midY)
        redPoint.zPosition = 3
        redPoint.anchorPoint = node1.anchorPoint
        redPoint.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: redPoint.size)
        redPoint.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        bluePoint.position = CGPoint(x: node1.frame.maxX, y: node1.frame.midY)
        bluePoint.zPosition = 3
        bluePoint.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: bluePoint.size)
        bluePoint.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        greenPoint.position = CGPoint(x: node1.frame.midX, y: node1.frame.maxY)
        greenPoint.zPosition = 3
        greenPoint.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: greenPoint.size)
        greenPoint.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        brownPoint.position = CGPoint(x: node1.frame.midX, y: node1.frame.minY)
        brownPoint.zPosition = 3
        brownPoint.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: greenPoint.size)
        brownPoint.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        let joint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: node1.physicsBody!, bodyB: redPoint.physicsBody!, anchor: CGPoint(x: node1.frame.minX, y: node1.frame.midY))

        let joint2 = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: node1.physicsBody!, bodyB: bluePoint.physicsBody!, anchor: CGPoint(x: node1.frame.maxX, y: node1.frame.midY))

        let joint3 = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: node1.physicsBody!, bodyB: greenPoint.physicsBody!, anchor: CGPoint(x: node1.frame.midX, y: node1.frame.maxY))

        let joint4 = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: node1.physicsBody!, bodyB: brownPoint.physicsBody!, anchor: CGPoint(x: node1.frame.midX, y: node1.frame.minY))

        addChild(node1)
        addChild(redPoint)
        addChild(bluePoint)
        addChild(greenPoint)
        addChild(brownPoint)

        scene?.physicsWorld.add(joint)
        scene?.physicsWorld.add(joint2)
        scene?.physicsWorld.add(joint3)
        scene?.physicsWorld.add(joint4)
    } 

    func rotate(){
        let rotate1 = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi / 2, duration: 0.1)

        node1.run(rotate1)
    }

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let touch = touches.first else {return}
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let tappedNodes = nodes(at: location)

        if tappedNodes.contains(node1){
            rotate()
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: can you draw a diagram of what's connected to what and what is doing what and another that shows what you actually want?

Comment: Hey Confused, I want all the spritenodes to move with node1 90 degrees each time the user taps on node1. Ex. If redPopint is pointing upward when the player taps on node1 and it rotates 90 degrees clockwise, redPoint should be pointing to the right side. And so on.

Comment: d.i.a.g.r.a.m --- p.l.e.a.s.e